# How to show Parse Push Notification in notification bar while application is running?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using Parse to do push notifications and the issue I am running into is that while my application is running (either in the foreground or background) the phone's operating system does not show the push notification in the notification bar. What changes to my implementation do I need to make to see the push display on the notification bar?

My extended Application class has the following in onCreate()

```
// initialize Parse SDK
Parse.initialize(this, Constants.APPLICATION_ID_DEBUG, Constants.CLIENT_KEY_DEBUG);
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(Constants.CHANNEL, new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Logger.i(TAG, "successfully subscribed to broadcast channel");
        } else {
            Logger.e(TAG, "failed to subscribe for push: " + e);
        }
    }
});
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

I have a sign in system for my app, so I am using the ID of the logged in user as the Channel to subscribe users to. So in the first Activity of my app I call the following code snippet in onCreate().

```
private void registerNotifications() {
        List<String> arryChannel = new ArrayList<String>();
        arryChannel.add(session.id);

        ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        parseInstallation.put("channels", arryChannel);
        parseInstallation.saveEventually();
}
```

I also have a custom receiver that is working. Each time a push is sent out, it is being received by the onPushReceive method, however, I want the push to display in the notification bar.

```
public class ParsePushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = ParsePushReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPushOpen");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPushReceive");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. Although the answer provided by Sandra will make a push notification appear on the notification bar, it is not connected to Parse.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

This causes issues, because if you click on that notification the receiver you create extending ParsePushBroadcastReceiver will not register onPushOpen. My implementation for everything was correct, I only needed to add

```
super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
```

That will make the notification appear on the notification bar and also register clicks.

So make sure to make your receiver looks like this (at minimum)

```
public class ParsePushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = ParsePushReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPushOpen");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPushReceive");
        **super.onPushReceive(context, intent);**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `onPushReceive` method and the default behaviour will remain (show the notification in the status bar.
You are getting this behaviour because if the application is running the Parse Push notification will call the method `onPushReceive` that does nothing.

Comment: I am curious, is it standard implementation to take the received push notification, and then programmatically build the notification and push it out? I would have thought this would be handled by the operating system.

Comment: The only issue with this is that clicking on the push notification has no action. It does not call onPushOpen(). I believe I need to take this same concept, except send out a push notification using Parse.

Comment: To add an action to a Notification you need to attach a pending intent in the notification builder. 

Maybe if you dont extend the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver all the notifications go to the NotificationBar by default.

Comment: If I do that, what is point in using parse? I am trying to do this through Parse. I will try to attach a pending intent, however, I do not see the connection between Notification Manager and Parse backend.

Comment: You problem is that you are overriding `onPushReceive ` and you don't want to change the default behaviour. So, just remove the `onPushReceive ` method should fix your problem. Can you test it?

Comment: If you dont use the method you should remove it. I will update my answer.